# What browser versions are supported in v7 of adapter.js for webRTC?

Tags: webrtc, adapter

We are thinking about using adapter.js (https://github.com/webrtcHacks/adapter) as an adapter for webRTC.

Based on the comment in commits for v7 (https://github.com/webrtcHacks/adapter/releases) 'removed lots of cruft from Chrome and Firefox shims. If you need support for browsers which are older than two years stick with the old version'.

So what versions are currently supported?

There is no info in the documentation anywhere and it looks like those commits removed quite a lot of checks for browser versions (there is no diff version for commits =( )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/webrtcHacks/adapter/issues/881 gives you a better indication about what cruft was removed.

Basically adapter makes no promises beyond what is testable on CI, if you want support for older versions... test yourself (slimjetbrower.com provides old chrome versions for download)